# Inconveniente con el funcionamiento del virtualenv de Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

Cordial saludo equipo necesito preguntarles lo siguiente, tengo instalado el Python  versión 3.9.13, al darle el nombre a dicho entorno virtual, mediante lo siguiente:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

me muestra el siguiente error:

```
virtualenv : El término 'virtualenv' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe 
si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ virtualenv -p python3 env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Vale mencionar que tengo instalado el virtualenv, ya que en la partición  mi disco duro lo he instalado, de la siguiente manera:

```
D:\Python y mas para Pragma\MedalleroOlimpico> pip install virtualenv
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\hecamava\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (20.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.4.1 in c:\users\hecamava\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.5 in c:\users\hecamava\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2.4 in c:\users\hecamava\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.5.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\hecamava\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Pero al realizar lo siguiente

```
PS D:\Python y mas para Pragma\MedalOlim> virtualenv -p python3 env
```

Me muestra el error ya mencionado.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Haz esto otro: `python3.9 -m venv env`. Quizás (dependiendo de tu instalación) en vez de `python3.9` tengas que dar la ruta absoluta hasta el lugar donde tengas el python.exe de esa versión

Comment: Ah, y no necesitas instalar virtualenv. El soporte para entornos virtuales ya viene en python 3.9, en forma de módulo (por eso la recomendación del comentario anterior, ejecutar ese módulo con la opción `-m` del intérprete)